# Reverse of Words in Character Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a char array `{'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','i','n'};` I want to do the reverse of order of sentence in array like {Win Hello}. How can i do this in java.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Suggestion: try splitting the array on values `' '`.

Comment: If you want to reverse the char array by words and not use extra memory, refer this approach. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/program-to-reverse-a-sentence-words-stored-as-character-array-in-cplusplus

Answer (score 1):

This example solution works for char array and String:

```
public char[] reverseWords(final char[] input){
    return reverseWords(new String(input)).toCharArray();
}
public String reverseWords(final String input){
    //Cut words to array
    final String[] words = input.split(" ");

    String result="";
    //Reverse array
    for (int i=words.length-1; i>-1; i--){
            result += words[i]+" ";
    }
    result = result.trim();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char ch[]={'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','i','n'};
String s=new String(ch);
String temp[]=s.split(" ");
s=""+temp[1]+" "+temp[0];
ch=s.toCharArray();
```

You can reverse it by above algo.Now you can convert it char array.

Comment: What if there are more than two words? For example: char ch[]={'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','i','n',' ','H','o','w',' ','a','r','e',' ','y','o','u'}. Your solution is not generic.