# How to reverse character elements in array using java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, reverse

I've created a small code that asks the user to input any word, then it will reverse it. I can't figure out how to reverse it so help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
package Test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMain {
public static void main(String[]args){

    String word = getWord();
    char[]wordArray;
    wordArray = word.toCharArray();
    System.out.print("NORMAL WORD: " + word + "\n");
    System.out.print("REVERSE WORD: ");


}

public static String getWord(){
    Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word;
    System.out.print("Enter a word:");
    word = hold.nextLine();
    return word;
}
}
```

Comment: Create a second array, loop over the first  placing each character at the opposite end of the new array ... May something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811667/reverse-of-words-in-character-array)

Comment: Just a side note, but instead of putting "\n" at the end of your print statement you can just change it to a System.out.println() and it will automatically add the new line at the end.

Answer (score 2):

StringBuilder have a reverse method.

```
 System.out.print("REVERSE WORD: " + new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString());
```

Or if you don't want to use inbuilt methods

```
String result= "";
for(int i=word.length(); i>0; i--) {
    result+= word.charAt(i-1);
}  
 System.out.print("REVERSE WORD: " + result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "Stack Overflow";
        char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("NORMAL WORD=" + Arrays.toString(wordArray));
        test.reverse(wordArray);
        System.out.println("REVERSE WORD=" + Arrays.toString(wordArray));
    }

    public static void reverse(char[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            return;
        }
        int i = 0;
        int j = array.length - 1;
        char tmp;
        while (j > i) {
            tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = tmp;
            j--;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
NORMAL WORD=[S, t, a, c, k,  , O, v, e, r, f, l, o, w]
REVERSE WORD=[w, o, l, f, r, e, v, O,  , k, c, a, t, S]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do this:**
1. Convert the string into a character array.
2. Swap the elements (first and last  -> second and second last -> ... Till the middle).
3. You will get a linear complexity of O(n/2) = O(n).

```
public static String reverseWord(String str)
{
    if(str.length()>0)
    {
        char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
        int length = arr.length;
        for(int i=0; i<length/2; i++)
        {
            char temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[length-i-1];
            arr[length-i-1] = temp;
        }
        return new String(arr);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use StringBuilder for constructed the reversed string.
In your main method.

```
    String word = getWord();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        sb.insert(0, c);
    }
    String reversed = sb.toString();
    System.out.print("NORMAL WORD: " + word);
    System.out.print("REVERSE WORD: " + reversed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the code in `main`:

```
char[]wordArray = word.toCharArray();
```

The `String` is a group of `char`s with one after the other.

We need to add each `char` to the beginning of the result in a loop:

```
String result = "";
for(char wordChar : word.toCharArray()) {
    result = wordChar + result;
}
```

This would cause the first `char` to go last and the second to go second to last etc. This way we can reverse the order of the `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String a = "12345";
    char [] original= a.toCharArray();
    char[] reverse = new char[a.length()];
    int j =0;
    for(int i=reverse.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        reverse[j] = original[i]; 
        j++;
    }

    System.out.println(new String(reverse));
}
```